# Half circular progress bar with gradient swift

Tags: ios, swift, progress-bar, gradient, swift4.2

I want to create a **`half circular progress bar`** with gradient colour in iOS using swift. The minimum value of progress bar is 300 and maximum value of progress bar is 900. The current value of the progress bar is dynamic. I am attaching screenshot ans css for colour reference. Can someone please provide me a small working demo?

[image: Half Circular progress]

below is the CSS -

```
/* Layout Properties */
top: 103px;
left: 105px;
width: 165px;
height: 108px;

/* UI Properties */

 background: transparent linear-gradient
(269deg, #32E1A0 0%, #EEED56 23%, #EFBF39 50%, #E59148 75%, #ED4D4D 100%)
 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
 opacity: 1;
```

[image: Properties]

Comment: you can use this pod: https://github.com/luispadron/UICircularProgressRing

Comment: Or if you want to create it by yourself, here is a nice tutorial : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/create-circular-progress-bar-in-ios

Comment: I am working on something similar and im wondering if there's a SwiftUI solution to this?

Comment: I started a bounty for SwiftUI solution

Answer (score 3):

this could solve your problem in swiftui

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var progressValue: Float = 0.3
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    @State private var degress: Double = -110
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            ZStack{
                
                ProgressBar(progress: self.$progressValue)
                    .frame(width: 250.0, height: 250.0)
                    .padding(40.0).onReceive(timer) { _ in
                        withAnimation {
                            if progressValue < 0.8999996 {
                                progressValue += 0.0275
                            }
                        }
                    }
                
                ProgressBarTriangle(progress: self.$progressValue).frame(width: 280.0, height: 290.0).rotationEffect(.degrees(degress), anchor: .bottom)
                    .offset(x: 0, y: -150).onReceive(timer) { input in
                        withAnimation(.linear(duration: 0.01).speed(200)) {
                            if degress < 110.0 {
                                degress += 10
                            }
                            print(degress)
                        }
                    }
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
    
    struct ProgressBar: View {
        @Binding var progress: Float
        
        var body: some View {
            ZStack {
                Circle()
                    .trim(from: 0.3, to: 0.9)
                    .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 12.0, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
                    .opacity(0.3)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(54.5))
                
                Circle()
                    .trim(from: 0.3, to: CGFloat(self.progress))
                    .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 12.0, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
                    .fill(AngularGradient(gradient: Gradient(stops: [
                        .init(color: Color.init(hex: "ED4D4D"), location: 0.39000002),
                        .init(color: Color.init(hex: "E59148"), location: 0.48000002),
                        .init(color: Color.init(hex: "EFBF39"), location: 0.5999999),
                        .init(color: Color.init(hex: "EEED56"), location: 0.7199998),
                        .init(color: Color.init(hex: "32E1A0"), location: 0.8099997)]), center: .center))
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(54.5))
                
                VStack{
                    Text("824").font(Font.system(size: 44)).bold().foregroundColor(Color.init(hex: "314058"))
                    Text("Great Score!").bold().foregroundColor(Color.init(hex: "32E1A0"))
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    struct ProgressBarTriangle: View {
        @Binding var progress: Float
        
        
        var body: some View {
            ZStack {
                Image("triangle").resizable().frame(width: 10, height: 10, alignment: .center)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

extension Color {
    init(hex: String) {
        let hex = hex.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.alphanumerics.inverted)
        var int: UInt64 = 0
        Scanner(string: hex).scanHexInt64(&int)
        let a, r, g, b: UInt64
        switch hex.count {
        case 3: // RGB (12-bit)
            (a, r, g, b) = (255, (int >> 8) * 17, (int >> 4 & 0xF) * 17, (int & 0xF) * 17)
        case 6: // RGB (24-bit)
            (a, r, g, b) = (255, int >> 16, int >> 8 & 0xFF, int & 0xFF)
        case 8: // ARGB (32-bit)
            (a, r, g, b) = (int >> 24, int >> 16 & 0xFF, int >> 8 & 0xFF, int & 0xFF)
        default:
            (a, r, g, b) = (1, 1, 1, 0)
        }
        
        self.init(
            .sRGB,
            red: Double(r) / 255,
            green: Double(g) / 255,
            blue:  Double(b) / 255,
            opacity: Double(a) / 255
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: this is animated just for fun. you could initialize progressValue and you are good to go.

Comment: i also used static values just to demonstrate the solution you could make them dynamic in your own code.

Comment: How do you put a triangle to indicate value? I need the triangle because my meter is not a "progress bar".

Comment: i have added the triangle but @John please make the values dynamic when you want to use it.

Comment: i noticed that this component takes a full circle's height, despite that it's only half a circle. How do i fix it?

Comment: I also noticed that the triangle takes up some space, pushing the circle in other direction. For example, when triangle is on the left hand side, the circle is slightly on the right hand side. There's some offset.

Comment: @John I'm making an open source for the dynamic partial circular progress bar on GitHub. I will put the link here tomorrow.

Comment: @John check this repo. I made it so anyone can play around with the progress bar and angular gradient. hope it helps https://github.com/al100/SwiftPartialCircularProgressBar

Comment: So in your GitHub screenshot, there's a blank space on the bottom of the progress bar. Is there a way to avoid it? I am thinking about using a custom path instead of `Circle()`

Comment: Please clone the projec and test. There is no extra space it the problem with screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

you can create not same but similar progress bar with framework called 
**[MKMagneticProgress](https://github.com/malkouz/MKMagneticProgress)**

example code :-

```
import MKMagneticProgress

@IBOutlet weak var magProgress:MKMagneticProgress!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    magProgress.setProgress(progress: 0.5, animated: true)
    magProgress.progressShapeColor = UIColor.blue
    magProgress.backgroundShapeColor = UIColor.yellow
    magProgress.titleColor = UIColor.red
    magProgress.percentColor = UIColor.black

    magProgress.lineWidth = 10
    magProgress.orientation = .top
    magProgress.lineCap = .round

    magProgress.title = "Title"
    magProgress.percentLabelFormat = "%.2f%%"

}
```

i hope it will work ... :)

Comment: Is there a SwiftUI solution for this (without using UIViewRepresentable wrapper?)

Answer (score -1):

I implemented something like your progress bar,
used this for level up - gain exp. progress.,

if you go from 300 to 1000, total bar is 1500
progressFrom: 300/1500, progressTo: 1000/1500 ..

```
func progressAnimation(duration: TimeInterval, progressFrom: CGFloat, progressTo: CGFloat) {
    if progressFrom == 0 {
        baseProgressLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
    }
    
    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(center: CGPoint(x: 93.0, y: 93.0), size: CGSize(width: 178, height: 178)))
    
    progressLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
    progressLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    progressLayer.strokeColor = getColor(progress: progressTo).cgColor
    progressLayer.lineWidth = 8.0
    layer.addSublayer(progressLayer)
    layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat(90 * Double.pi / 180), 0, 0, -1)
    
    let end = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    end.fromValue = progressFrom
    end.toValue = progressTo
    end.duration = duration * 0.85
    end.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.linear)
    end.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.forwards
    end.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    
    let color = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeColor")
    color.fromValue = getColor(progress: progressFrom).cgColor
    color.toValue = getColor(progress: progressTo).cgColor
    color.duration = duration * 0.85
    color.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.linear)
    color.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.forwards
    color.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    
    let group = CAAnimationGroup()
    group.animations = [end, color]
    group.duration = duration * 0.85
    progressLayer.strokeStart = progressFrom
    progressLayer.strokeEnd = progressTo
    progressLayer.add(group, forKey: "move")

    if progressFrom != 0 {
        let color2 = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeColor")
        color2.fromValue = getColor(progress: progressFrom).cgColor
        color2.toValue = getColor(progress: progressTo).cgColor
        color2.duration = duration * 0.85
        color2.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.linear)
        color2.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.forwards
        color2.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        
       baseProgressLayer.add(color2, forKey: "baseColor")
    }
    
}
```

there is a extension for getting color for progress

extension CircularProgressBar {

```
private func getColor (progress: CGFloat) -> UIColor{
    if progress >= 0 && progress <= 0.5{
        return UIColor(red: CGFloat(255 / 255), green: CGFloat((0+((108-0)*progress*2)) / 255), blue: 0, alpha: 1.0)
    }
    else if progress > 0.5 && progress <= 1.0 {
        return UIColor(red: CGFloat((255-((255-126)*(progress-0.5)*2)) / 255), green: CGFloat((108+((211-108)*(progress-0.5)*2)) / 255), blue: CGFloat((0+((33-0)*(progress-0.5)*2)) / 255), alpha: 1.0)
    }
    else {
        return UIColor.green
    }
}
```

}